# Use jsoup to parse div tags in a forum

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup, processing

I am using the jSoup library in conjunction with Processing to retrieve certain text from a forum. I am looking to only scrape posts from a certain user in a certain thread.

These are div-tags containing username information and the posts:

**username:**

```
<span itemprop="creator name" class="author vcard"><a hovercard-ref="member" hovercard-id="104291" data-ipb="noparse" class="url fn name  ___hover___member _hoversetup" href="[link to user's profile here]" title="" id="anonymous_element_4"><span itemprop="name">djrajio</span></a></span>
```

**posts:**

```
<div itemprop="commentText" class="post entry-content ">[post text here]</div>
```

I tried following [this](https://github.com/jeffThompson/ProcessingTeachingSketches/blob/master/DataVisualization/ParseHTML_WithJSoup/ParseHTML_WithJSoup.pde) tutorial but the selector syntax for div tags wasn't so clear to me.

Can someone point in the right direction to be able to just scrape texts from a specific user?

[Here](http://illtellyoulater.com/div.txt) is the html containing the two div tags:

Comment: Do you have a more complete example of the html? Post the parent element that contains them

Comment: updated the first post with the html! :)

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes then you should accept it so the topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://illtellyoulater.com/div.txt").get();

    Elements posts = page.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("id", "post_id_");

    for(Element post : posts) {
        if( post.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop", "creator name").get(0).text().trim().equals("djrajio") ) {
            arr.add(post.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop","commentText").get(0).text());
        }
    }


    System.out.println(arr.toString());
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is for just one page. If you want to visit all the pages of the thread, or all the threads of the forum you will have to use a crawler.